# Application architecture MySQL / PHP / Java / AngularJS

Tags: mysql, rest, web-applications, architecture, software-design

**Intro:**
We are redesigning our application architecture and we are about to make import design decisions.

**Background and dependencies:** All data is stored in distributed MySQL databases. We have two systems that access the databases - one that performs routinely tasks, programmed in Java and our web application - currently Apache2, PHP (Zend1 framework) and JavaScript (jQuery).
The Java app will not be redesigned and the database should remain MySQL.
The web application is supposed to be changed to a REST API and a modern, fast, real-time AngularJS frontend that communicate over JSON.
Since we already programmed all backend functionality in PHP, it would probably make sense to stick with PHP for the REST API - but this is not a must if it makes future development easier, faster and future-proof.
The Java app and the web application share some MySQL queries.

**Questions:**

1. Shared MySQL queries: Should we implement them as a) MySQL procedures / views, b) separately in Java and PHP, c) independent service (e.g. another REST API)
2. Should we stick with Zend1 or rather use a more suited PHP REST framework (such as Slim or Restler or something else)?
3. Should we stick with Apache2/PHP for the REST API at all (maybe use Node.js instead)?

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This post is probably designed to start a flame war... but...

[Never rewrite code from scratch](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html).  Take what you have, and refactor it to create modern restful services on top of it.

Do it as a slow migration, rewriting one page at a time in a like-for-like manner.

You will have far fewer bugs, it will cost less, and totally avoid [second-system syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-system_effect)

Comment: Haha, that Blog post by J. Spolsky is awesome (and informative) - thanks

Comment: The article is old(2000) and a lot has changed over the years, but I agree with the author: `Never rewrite code from scrath`. I like the following fact he mentioned: `When you throw away code and start from scratch, you are throwing away all that knowledge. All those collected bug fixes. Years of programming work.`

Comment: +1 for never rewrite code from scratch ! My close friend loves coding so much that he rewrite everything. He always argues that "your approach here" is bad and buggy. Now that I am glad that you and many others agree with me on cost-effective approach.